# Solr 4 replacement for SolrPluginUtils.addOrReplaceResults?

Tags: solr

What is the replacement method for SolrPluginUtils.addOrReplaceResults in Solr 4.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, this method is removed from SolrPluginUtils class. 
But you can write your own. The code is very straight forward

```
 public static void addOrReplaceResults(SolrQueryResponse rsp, SolrDocumentList docs) 
  {
    NamedList vals = rsp.getValues();
    int idx = vals.indexOf( "response", 0 );
    if( idx >= 0 ) {
      log.debug("Replacing DocList with SolrDocumentList " + docs.size());
      vals.setVal( idx, docs );
    }
    else {
      log.debug("Adding SolrDocumentList response" + docs.size());
      vals.add( "response", docs );
    }
  }
```